# Show/Hide form submit button with ngIf using observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I would like to show the submit button of a form when the form is valid. To pass the form group to the various components that compose the form, I use a FormGroup Observable like this.

```
  private declarationForm: BehaviorSubject<FormGroup | undefined>;
  declarationForm$: Observable<FormGroup>;

  constructor(){
    this.declarationForm = new BehaviorSubject(
            this.fb.group(new DeclarationForm(new DeclarationModel()))
    );

    this.declarationForm$ = this.declarationForm.asObservable();
 }
```

Then, on the component holding the submit button, I would like to do smth like this:

```
<div *ngIf="declarationForm.valid">

  <button>Submit</button>

</div>
```

What I've tried so far is, subscribing to the `declarationForm$` observable on the AfterViewInit hook, which results in the `Expression has changed after it was checked` error and then I tried passing the observable to the template like this..

```
  <div *ngIf="declarationForm$ | async as form">

  </div>
```

but I don't know how to get the `valid` property...

Does anyone know how should I write this?

Comment: Here is a blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rmcf4
I don't get the `Expression Has Changed..` error on stackblitz though... What should I do?

Comment: That's weird. Do you have the same code on local?

Comment: It's a lot more complicated, but at its core it follows the same logic... I managed to solve it by creating a new boolean observable, that holds the valid state only. As far as I understand, binding the button disabled property (as seen below)  to a property of the observable throws the error because angular checks the disabled property synchronously and the result from the observable comes after that, so the value changes...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmaqcv).

Comment: I am using an observable... See the blitz on the comment above. The error appears on my local  environment only. On stackblitz seems fine...

Comment: I have updated the above stackbiltz to use your example, try it out. It uses the async pipe to handle all the subscribe and unsubscribing.

Comment: This is what I was looking for in the first place, but it doesn't seem to work... Same error again...

Comment: Why are using this approach anyway. Why are you using an Observable FormGroup, the FormGroup has its own observables you can subscribe too. If you aren't planning on emitting a new FormGroup then you don't need this methodology.

Comment: Because I have a  form with 180+ inputs, spread in 80+ components and I need to manage it in one place...

Comment: Ok I have updated the stackblitz link. It now only creates one observable in the service and uses shareReply to share the same observable across your components.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the valid status with async pipe

```
<div *ngIf="(declarationForm$ | async) as form">
  {{form.valid | json}}
  <button [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work either... The same error is thrown again. The ngIf is async but the disabled property throws the error as its initial value is set to true. The only way that seems to work is using a variable and setting it to false on the OnInit and then binding the same variable to the value of the observable on the AfterViewInit, so the value doesnt change from true to false. But what if the initial state of the form is valid and the observable returns true? Same thing...

Comment: strange, how come it doesn't throw any error 
please take a look on the updated stackbliz 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmdqet?file=src/app/submit-button/submit-button.component.html

Comment: Stackblitz works fine... When I serve it locally I encounter the problem....

Comment: It could be some inconsistent code in that case. I used this kinda logic and syntax before without any problem

Comment: I know! This should have worked...  I'll have to take a different approach...

Comment: Good hope it helps